# Truffle migrate: unknown network "development"

Tags: truffle-migration

I'm using macOS High Sierra. I installed truffle and ganache-cli as below

```
npm install -g truffle
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

Then I created a directory and cd to it to run the test

```
mkdir ethereumTest
cd ethereumTest
```

I initiate the truffle and compile it

```
truffle init
truffle compile
```

Since I'm on Mac, I changed the `truffle.js` file as below

```
module.exports = {
   network: {
     development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "*"
    }
  }
};
```

I opened another terminal and ran ganache-cli
    ganache-cli

But when I tried to migrate to the network in the previous terminal, it gives error

```
truffle migrate
```

It gives

```
Unknown network "[object Object]". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.

truffle network --network development
```

It gives

```
Unknown network "development". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.
```

I also tried the following

- remove `truffle-config.js`
- change `truffle-config.js` as the same as `truffle.js`
- In the `truffle.js` file, change `host` to `localhost`

But none of them works, any other suggestion?

Comment: `truffle network`??? I think what you mean is `truffle migrate`.

Comment: @goodvigration, oh, yeah, thanks. Already edited it.

Comment: `truffle-config.js` and `truffle.js` are the same, you only need one of them (on Windows, calling `truffle` might lead to a "collision" with `truffle.js`, so better use `truffle-config.js`, but you're not even using Windows).

Comment: did you launch `ganache-cli` before migrating?  also, what do you get with `truffle develop` ?

Comment: @NikitaFuchs, I did launch ganache-cli before migrating. And interesting, `truffle develop` gives `Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/`, but in the ganache-cli, the port is indeed 8545 instead of 9545

Comment: @NikitaFuchs, and I just tried 9545, it does not work either.

Comment: What version of truffle and ganache are you using? Are you in the correct directory when you execute `truffle migrate`? Keep only one of `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js` not both.

Comment: @Ismael, truffle is v.4.1.13, and ganache is `Ganache CLI v6.1.6 (ganache-core: 2.1.5)`. I believe I'm in the correct directory. And I did try remove one of them, but still did not work.

Comment: We are using the same versions and it does work here. What version of node are you using? If you are using node v8 or newer it should work. I'd suggest to report to truffle developers.

Answer (score 1):

Change your "**network**" to "**networks**" in the truffle.js configuration file. Refer https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration for example configurations.